# MDX Query with two or more date ranges

Tags: sql, mdx, olap, dimension, mondrian

Is it possible to put two or more data ranges in MDX Query?

This part of mdx query:

```
FILTER([Time].[Date].MEMBERS,[Time].CURRENTMEMBER IN([Time].[2013].[2].[2013-02-01] : [Time].[2014].[7].[2014-07-07]))
```

converted to SQL  is:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2014-07-07'
```

**What I want to achieve in MDX:**

SQL:

```
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2014-07-07') OR (Date Between '2012-07-06' AND '2012-08-17');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ":" operator just creates a naturally ordered Set of all Members between the two Members (inclusive).

You can use Set notation to create a set containing the elements of other Sets as long as they are in the same Hierarchy.

```
FILTER([Time].[Date].MEMBERS,[Time].CURRENTMEMBER IN(
    { 
        [Time].[2013].[2].[2013-02-01] : [Time].[2014].[7].[2014-07-07], 
        [Time].[2012].[7].[2012-07-06] : [Time].[2012].[8].[2012-08-17]
    })
```

Comment: Wait, you are doubling [Time].CURRENTMEMBER inside IN(..)?

Comment: oops, poor copy and paste, should just be the Time : Time portion

Comment: Fantastic! +50 if I could

Comment: Not working for Microsoft SSAS = "The syntax for 'IN' is incorrect."